# Trying to get the minimum value from dataset using reduceByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have my data like this

```
id,category,price,description
1,2,59.98,xyz
2,2,129.99,pqr
3,2,89.99,mno
```

I would like to retrieve the minimum float value using reduceByKey as a tuple by category
My expected answer should be like this `(2,59.98)`
I tried It like this but it  says error

```
val minPricedProducts= products.map(x=>(x.split(",")(1).toInt,x.split(",")(2).toFloat)).reduceByKey((a,b)=> if(a._1 < b._1) a else b).map(rec._1)
```

> :33: error: value _2 is not a member of Float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, this will work:

```
    val minPricedProducts= products.map{ x =>
       val d = x.split(",")
       (d(1).toInt,d(2).toFloat)
    }.reduceByKey( (a,b) => if(a < b) a else b)
```

`a` and `b` are not tuples since `reduceByKey` already extracts the value part of the tuple for you, so you don't need the `_1`s.

Note that I did the split once, you don't want it do do twice since it takes twice as much time and memory.

Also, using `.reduceByKey( (a,b) => Math.min(a,b) )` instead of the `if` is probably more readable.

I am not sure how you got an `error: value _2 is not a member of Float` when `_2` 
 is not in the code you posted, did you mean `_1` ?

It is worth noticing that there are better way to do this, since it's a CSV file
you could just read it with `read.csv()` and then you could just use `df.groupBy("category").agg(min("price"))`.